# k=Fold Cross Validation Issues

Tags: regression, cross-validation, polynomial

I am trying to do a k=fold cross-validation on a polynomial regression. Unfortunately, I am getting an MSE that is vastly different from the MSE I would get if I were to just manually change the degrees in the code. Below is my code:

#### Validation Approach

```
# Polynomial Using sales, discount and quantity as dependent variables (degree = 2)

set.seed(123)
train_index <- sample(x = 1:nrow(superstore), size=floor(nrow(superstore)/2))
train_df <- superstore[train_index, ]
test_df <- superstore[-train_index, ]

mod2 <- lm(profit ~ poly(sales, discount, quantity, degree = 2), data = train_df)

mse_train2 <- mean(mod2$residuals^2)

pred2 <- predict(object=mod2, type = "response", newdata = test_df)
mse_test2 <- mean((test_df$profit - pred2)^2)
mse_test2
mean((pred2-test_df$profit)^2)
```

#### K-Fold Cross Validation (k=10)

```
mse_vec <- rep(0, 10)
for (i in 1:10) {
  mod_i <- lm(profit ~ poly(sales, discount, quantity, degree = i), data = train_df)
  pred_i <- predict(object = mod_i, type = "response", newdata = test_df)
  mse_vec[i] <- mean((pred_i - test_df$profit)^2)
}

tibble(degree = 1:10,
       mse = mse_vec) %>%
  ggplot(aes(degree, mse)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line()
```

Comment: Could you add the graph and indicate where the difference is exactly.

Comment: You get different mse, but you also have different methods. So is there something unexpected?

Comment: In your loop you are not doing 10-fold cross-validation, but instead n/2-fold cross validation with different polynomial orders.